# Stop labels from overlapping in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a large area with lots of small 'sites' within it.  I want to label each of these 'sites' but when I zoom out to 1:95,000 the labels overlap so I cannot read some of them.  Is there a way to prevent the labels from overlapping with each other but still show the area?

I have added an example below.  I really want to be able to read all the labels, no matter if the label is directly above the 'site'.

[image: overlapping labels]

Comment: Please provide more detail like how many layer, how many site, what do you call a "small" site and what labeling setting did you use....

Comment: Thanks for providing 'reasonable' screenshots ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels will only overlap each other if you chose the option to "show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)". Otherwise, QGIS will normally only display as many labels as possible in the current map extent, with **your chosen label settings**.

So the solution is to use different label settings, for example:

- smaller font size
- further distance, allowing labels to be placed further from their geographic feature

See the answer I posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341271/81764) for more detailed explanations.